# Arduino uno with microled library; draw shaped

Tags: arduino-uno, compilation-errors

I am really sorry for bothering you but i need help, again, with my arduino code. I am still learning so i make mistakes.

I am trying to draw shaped on i2c screen with Microled library. My code isn`t compiling, error is Unexpected declaration before { . That is one problem. I would also like to draw rectangle without edges, both empty and filled but i am struggling how to declare it, should i declare 4 lines or maybe display bitmap.

Anyway my code is here

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <MicroLCD.h>

LCD_SH1106 lcd; /* for SH1106 OLED module */
//LCD_SSD1306 lcd; /* for SSD1306 OLED module */

static const PROGMEM uint8_t smile[48 * 48 / 8] = {
0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x80,0xC0,0xE0,0xF0,0xF8,0xF8,0xFC,0xFC,0xFE,0xFE,0x7E,0x7F,0x7F,0x3F,0x3F,0x3F,0x3F,0x3F,0x3F,0x3F,0x3F,0x3F,0x3F,0x7F,0x7F,0x7E,0xFE,0xFE,0xFC,0xFC,0xF8,0xF8,0xF0,0xE0,0xC0,0x80,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,
0x00,0xC0,0xF0,0xFC,0xFE,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0x3F,0x1F,0x0F,0x07,0x03,0x01,0x00,0x80,0x80,0x80,0x80,0x80,0x80,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x80,0x80,0x80,0x80,0x80,0x80,0x00,0x01,0x03,0x07,0x0F,0x1F,0x3F,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFE,0xFC,0xF0,0xC0,0x00,
0xFE,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0x07,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x06,0x1F,0x1F,0x1F,0x3F,0x1F,0x1F,0x02,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x06,0x1F,0x1F,0x1F,0x3F,0x1F,0x1F,0x02,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFE,
0x7F,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xE0,0x00,0x00,0x30,0xF8,0xF8,0xF8,0xF8,0xE0,0xC0,0x80,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x80,0xC0,0xE0,0xF8,0xF8,0xFC,0xF8,0x30,0x00,0x00,0xE0,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0x7F,
0x00,0x03,0x0F,0x3F,0x7F,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFC,0xF8,0xF0,0xE1,0xC7,0x87,0x0F,0x1F,0x3F,0x3F,0x3E,0x7E,0x7C,0x7C,0x7C,0x78,0x78,0x7C,0x7C,0x7C,0x7E,0x3E,0x3F,0x3F,0x1F,0x0F,0x87,0xC7,0xE1,0xF0,0xF8,0xFC,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0x7F,0x3F,0x0F,0x03,0x00,
0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x03,0x07,0x0F,0x1F,0x1F,0x3F,0x3F,0x7F,0x7F,0x7E,0xFE,0xFE,0xFC,0xFC,0xFC,0xFC,0xFC,0xFC,0xFC,0xFC,0xFC,0xFC,0xFE,0xFE,0x7E,0x7F,0x7F,0x3F,0x3F,0x1F,0x1F,0x0F,0x07,0x03,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,
};

static const PROGMEM uint8_t tick[16 * 16 / 8] =
{0x00,0x80,0xC0,0xE0,0xC0,0x80,0x00,0x80,0xC0,0xE0,0xF0,0xF8,0xFC,0x78,0x30,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x03,0x07,0x0F,0x1F,0x1F,0x1F,0x0F,0x07,0x03,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00};

static const PROGMEM uint8_t cross[16 * 16 / 8] =
{0x00,0x0C,0x1C,0x3C,0x78,0xF0,0xE0,0xC0,0xE0,0xF0,0x78,0x3C,0x1C,0x0C,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x30,0x38,0x3C,0x1E,0x0F,0x07,0x03,0x07,0x0F,0x1E,0x3C,0x38,0x30,0x00,0x00};

void setup()
{
  delay(1000);  
  delay(1000);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(40, 1);
  delay(500);
}

void line()
{
int x0 = 7; int y0 = 7;   // (x0,y0) = (7, 7)
int x1 = 42; int y1 = 24; // (x1,y1) = (42, 24)
oled.line(x0, y0, x1, y1);  // Draw a line from (x0,y0) to (x1,y1);
oled.display(); // Draw to the screen
}

void rectangle()
{
int x0 = 7; int y0 = 5;
int width = 24;
int height = 13;
oled.rect(x0, y0, width, height);  
oled.display();
}

void filled()
{
oled.rectFill(7, 5, 35, 5); // Fill a rectangle from (7, 5) to (42, 10)
int radius = 13;
}

void circle()
oled.circle(LCDWIDTH/2, LCDHEIGHT/2, radius);   
oled.display(); // Draw to the screen

oled.circleFill(42, 20, 7); // Fill a circle, 7 radius, centered at (42, 20)
oled.display(); // Draw to the screen
}

void loop()
{
  line();  
  rectangle();   
  filled();  
  circle();  
}
void printTitle(String title, int font)
{
  int middleX = oled.getLCDWidth() / 2;
  int middleY = oled.getLCDHeight() / 2;

  oled.clear(PAGE);
  oled.setFontType(font);
  oled.setCursor(middleX - (oled.getFontWidth() * (title.length()/2)),
                 middleY - (oled.getFontWidth() / 2));
  oled.print(title);
  oled.display();
  delay(1500);
  oled.clear(PAGE);
}
```

---

Full error is this

```
Arduino: 1.8.6 (Linux), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"

In file included from /home/lutherus/scripts/sketch_nov14a/sketch_nov14a.ino:3:0:
/home/lutherus/builds/Arduino/build/linux/work/libraries/MicroLCD/MicroLCD.h:38:43: warning: '__progmem__' attribute ignored [-Wattributes]
     virtual void draw(const PROGMEM byte* buffer, byte width, byte height) {}
                                           ^
In file included from /home/lutherus/scripts/sketch_nov14a/sketch_nov14a.ino:3:0:
/home/lutherus/builds/Arduino/build/linux/work/libraries/MicroLCD/MicroLCD.h:67:35: warning: '__progmem__' attribute ignored [-Wattributes]
     void draw(const PROGMEM byte* buffer, byte width, byte height);
                                   ^
/home/lutherus/builds/Arduino/build/linux/work/libraries/MicroLCD/MicroLCD.h:84:35: warning: '__progmem__' attribute ignored [-Wattributes]
     void draw(const PROGMEM byte* buffer, byte width, byte height);
                                   ^
/home/lutherus/scripts/sketch_nov14a/sketch_nov14a.ino: In function 'void line()':
sketch_nov14a:39: error: 'oled' was not declared in this scope
 oled.line(x0, y0, x1, y1);  // Draw a line from (x0,y0) to (x1,y1);
 ^
/home/lutherus/scripts/sketch_nov14a/sketch_nov14a.ino: In function 'void rectangle()':
sketch_nov14a:48: error: 'oled' was not declared in this scope
 oled.rect(x0, y0, width, height);  // Draw a rectange from (7,5) to (31,18)
 ^
/home/lutherus/scripts/sketch_nov14a/sketch_nov14a.ino: In function 'void filled()':
sketch_nov14a:54: error: 'oled' was not declared in this scope
 oled.rectFill(7, 5, 35, 5); // Fill a rectangle from (7, 5) to (42, 10)
 ^
/home/lutherus/scripts/sketch_nov14a/sketch_nov14a.ino: At global scope:
sketch_nov14a:61: error: expected initializer before 'oled'
 oled.circle(LCDWIDTH/2, LCDHEIGHT/2, radius);   
 ^
sketch_nov14a:62: error: 'oled' does not name a type
 oled.display(); // Draw to the screen
 ^
sketch_nov14a:64: error: 'oled' does not name a type
 oled.circleFill(42, 20, 7); // Fill a circle, 7 radius, centered at (42, 20)
 ^
sketch_nov14a:65: error: 'oled' does not name a type
 oled.display(); // Draw to the screen
 ^
sketch_nov14a:67: error: expected declaration before '}' token
 }
 ^
exit status 1
'oled' was not declared in this scope

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

Comment: Is that really the full text of the error?  I've never seen that one before.  I would think that if you want someone else to find the problem, the exact error message would be helpful.  Don't try to paraphrase it because you cut out vital information.  I'm sure the compiler told you exactly what line it found a problem on.  Start by looking there.

Answer (score 0):

I notice that the circle function is missing an opening brace.  Not sure if that's the one that caused the error you see now but it definitely needs to be fixed.